# Why std::function works as an argument to std::not2?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, typedef

std::not2 is implemented in the following way:

```
template <class Predicate>
binary_negate<Predicate> not2 (const Predicate& pred)
{
    return binary_negate<Predicate>(pred);
}
```

It uses std::binary_negate in its implementation and binary_negate which is inherited from std::binary_function requires _Predicate::first_argument_type and _Predicate::second_argument_type in its templated arguments in the following way:

```
template <class _Predicate>
class binary_negate : public binary_function<typename _Predicate::first_argument_type,
                                             typename _Predicate::second_argument_type,
                                             bool>
{
    // ...
}
```

And my question is why I can write something like this if there are no typedefs for first_argument_type and second_argument_type in the Predicate that I am passing?

```
struct new_same
{
    bool operator()(int a, int b) const { return a == b; }
};
auto not_same = std::not2(std::function<bool(int, int)>(new_same()));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also a (from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/binary_negate)):

> ```
> template< class Predicate >           (since C++11)
> struct binary_negate;                 (deprecated in C++17)
>                                       (removed in C++20)
> ```

Further, [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) does have the following typdefs:

> ```
> first_argument_type    (deprecated in C++17)(removed in C++20)
> second_argument_type   (deprecated in C++17)(removed in C++20)
> ```

> why I can write something like this if there are no typedefs for first_argument_type and second_argument_type in the Predicate that I am passing?

The typedefs are there. `binary_negate` can get them from `Predicate` (which is a `std::function` in your case).

All this is deprecated in `C++17` and removed in `C++20`. I have to admit, that I cannot tell you what the replacement is.

Comment: Thanks, I did not find these typedefs in the <functional> header file, but they exist somewhere else. At least I see that they exist in cppreference.com docs.

Comment: @Oleg cppreference is usually quite accurate. In case I want more details I would look into the standard first rather than browsing the implementation. Its too easy to confuse implementation details with the actual things as specified

Comment: Regarding the deprecation and motivations to it (e.g. no replacment), see [N3145](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2010/n3145.html).

Answer (score 1):

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/not2):

> `not2` is a helper function to create a function object that returns the complement of the binary predicate function passed. The function object created is of type `std::binary_negate<Predicate>`.

and:

> The binary predicate type must define two member types, `first_argument_type` and `second_argument_type`, that are convertible to the predicate's parameter types. **The function objects obtained from** [...] **`std::function`**, or from another call to `std::not2` have these types defined, as are function objects derived from the deprecated `std::binary_function`.

In my implementation (MinGW with GCC 9.2.0), `std::function` derives from `_Maybe_unary_or_binary_function` which, when instantiated with 2 arguments, derives from `std::binary_function`.

---

Note that this feature is *deprecated*. I cannot, unfortunately, find any replacements for it as of right now.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at std::function implementation, you will see that it inherits a class named  _Maybe_unary_or_binary_function. This inheritance cause the std::function to inherit std::binary_function if number of parameters is two.

```
  template<typename _Res, typename... _ArgTypes>
    class function<_Res(_ArgTypes...)>
    : public _Maybe_unary_or_binary_function<_Res, _ArgTypes...>,
      private _Function_base
    {
        ...
    }
```

```
  template<typename _Res, typename... _ArgTypes>
    struct _Maybe_unary_or_binary_function { };

  /// Derives from @c unary_function, as appropriate.
  template<typename _Res, typename _T1>
    struct _Maybe_unary_or_binary_function<_Res, _T1>
    : std::unary_function<_T1, _Res> { };

  /// Derives from @c binary_function, as appropriate.
  template<typename _Res, typename _T1, typename _T2>
    struct _Maybe_unary_or_binary_function<_Res, _T1, _T2>
    : std::binary_function<_T1, _T2, _Res> { };
```

by inheritance from std::binary_function, first_argument_type and second_argument_type are added to the std::function:

```
template<typename _Arg1, typename _Arg2, typename _Result>
 struct binary_function
    {
      /// @c first_argument_type is the type of the first argument
      typedef _Arg1     first_argument_type; 

      /// @c second_argument_type is the type of the second argument
      typedef _Arg2     second_argument_type;

      /// @c result_type is the return type
      typedef _Result   result_type;
    };
```